# Why my build project Angular2 don't work in any apache server?

Tags: angularjs, apache, webpack, macos-sierra, apache2.4

**I turn my build angular project (ejected with Webpack) in server apache local in the mac OS Sierra, and I found a problem with resource file in index.html but when I turn the same build in Ubuntu project run correctly with no error.**

> I run the build project in the default server Apache on mac OS Sierra 10.12.4 :
>    [Result in mac OS Sierra 10.12.4 with default Apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPPa7.jpg)
>   (when I used MAMP PRO in macOS the status of loading files is 404)
>
> When I run the same build project in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS :
>   [Result in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with default Apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKKVN.jpg)

Version used :

- Angular: 2.4.8
- Angular CLI: 1.0.0-rc.0
- webpack: 2.2.1

Comment: changing base href="." worked for u ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's solved me:

https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-macos-sierra-10-12-bca5a5dfffba
the problem in my apache2 configuration not in the base href

Answer (score 0):

Its missing a valid base href, Make sure index.html contains

```
  <base href=".">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I change my index.html: 
[the result with base href="."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBlbu.jpg)

I think is not logical because in Ubuntu work correctly with default base href="/"
[Old index.html generted with build and work correct in Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUmsY.jpg)